# Nvidia update broke my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, upgrade

After update nvidia drivers to nvidia driver 470 ubuntu is not booting. This is definitely due to these drivers because when I switch to intel graphics everything works fine (my laptop has two graphics cards).
The screen it crashes on is:
`dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks` (sth like that).

I uninstalled the nvidia drivers, reinstalled them and this time the screen crashes on the logo at startup. This happens whether I update the whole system or just the nvidi drivers. I'm a new Linux user, so please be understanding.

I also add the packages that I update:

```bsh
libnss-systemd/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
libnvidia-cfg1-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-common-460/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-compute-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-compute-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-decode-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-decode-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-encode-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-encode-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-extra-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-fbc1-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-fbc1-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-gl-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-gl-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-ifr1-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libnvidia-ifr1-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
libpam-systemd/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
libsystemd0/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
libudev1/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.8.0.63.71~20.04.45 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8.0.59.66~20.04.42]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.8.0.63.71~20.04.45 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8.0.59.66~20.04.42]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.8.0.63.71~20.04.45 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8.0.59.66~20.04.42]
linux-libc-dev/focal-updates,focal-security 5.4.0-80.90 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0-77.86]
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1]
numix-icon-theme-circle/focal,focal 19.12.27+202107171547~ubuntu20.04.1 all [upgradable from: 19.12.27+202107012117~ubuntu20.04.1]
nvidia-compute-utils-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
nvidia-driver-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
nvidia-kernel-common-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
nvidia-kernel-source-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
nvidia-utils-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
python3-distupgrade/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:20.04.35 all [upgradable from: 1:20.04.33]
systemd-sysv/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
systemd-timesyncd/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
systemd/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:20.04.35 all [upgradable from: 1:20.04.33]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk/focal-updates,focal-updates 1:20.04.35 all [upgradable from: 1:20.04.33]
udev/focal-updates,focal-security 245.4-4ubuntu3.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 245.4-4ubuntu3.7]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460/focal-updates,focal-security 460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2]
```